# Include folder from D: drive on User folder on C: drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, user-accounts

On my Windows 7 computer I have 2 drives, C: and D:. On C: drive I have my system installation, and on the D: drive I have my personal data.

I want to sync data between C: and D: on the user folder, so everything will be in the same place, and I could treat D: files path as C: drive.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can move your profile to another directory, how that is done is documented, have you done that?  There is no way to have your profile directory on both drives though.

Comment: I don't want to move my profile, since after that I won't be able to upgrade later to Windows 10

Comment: Why would you think that? Win 10 fully supports folder redirection, it shouldn't be an issue like it was with Windows 8.x. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/upgrade-to-windows-10-from-windows-7-user-folder/2c7f838c-5326-4963-b91e-bd48edd7b245

Comment: Edit your question to specify which data exactly ( which folders ) you want to sync.  Your statement, "so everything will be in the same place", seems to indicate you want to move your user profile to your data partition.

Comment: Would a link to a folder on the other drive be good enough? I wonder if windows can do bind mounts...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NTFS, then you can use a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) ([MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363878(v=vs.85).aspx))

For example (in `cmd.exe` - make sure you quote or escape spaces):

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\My Folder" "D:\My Folder"
```

Afterwards, you can access `D:\My Folder` via your home directory (presuming `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` is your home directory).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without using cmd.exe too.

In Disk Management right click on the partition that you want to be linked.

Click Change Drive Letter and Paths.

Click Add

Then mount in the following empty NTFS folder.